# Converting yyyyWn format to yyyyww - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe, which has data in the format below:

```
ID    Date     Volume 
1    2019W1      9
1    2020W2     11
2    2019W1     39
2    2020W2     23
```

I want to convert this to the yyyyww format.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime(%Y%U)
```

this code doesn't quite work.

Error message:

```
 ValueError: ('Unknown string format: '2019W1')
```

Expected output:

```
ID     Date     Volume 
1    2019-01      9
1    2020-02     11
2    2019-01     39
2    2020-02     23
```

Comment: "doesn't quite work" -- well, how is your current output different from your expected output? You seem to have forgotten to show the results you wanted.

Comment: It doesn't quite work because I get an error; 'Unknown string format: '2019W1' '

Comment: Is `df.Date.replace(r"W(\d+)$", "-" + r"0\1", regex=True)` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Our primary task is to convert `YYYYWN` or `YYYYWNN` to `YYYY-NN`. Where `YYYY` is `Year`, `W` is `String` which we have to `replace`, and `NN` is `Number of Week`.

There are two scenarios for replacement. Detailed scenario with it's solution was stated below:-

**1. A week with Single Digit `WN` Format (for eg.:- 2019W1):-**

So, to replace `YYYYWN` with `YYYY-NN` we have to use the `replace` function with `RegEx`.

`RegEx` for `identification` of `WN` will be `W(\d)$` Where:-

- `W` is `Character 'W'` which we have to replace
- `(\d)` is used to identify `Single Digit` Numbers
- `$` is used to find `ending`. **for e.g.:-** in our case it is, `(\d)$`. So, it will find whether our `Pattern` is ending with single-digit or not.

`RegEx` for `Replacement` of `WN` will be `0\1` Where:-

- `0`:- Append `0` before week number
- `\1`:- For trailing `Single Week Digit` after `0`

**2. A week with Multiple Digit `WNN` Format (for eg.:- 2020W11):-**

`RegEx` for `identification` of `WNN` will be `W` where:-

- `W` is `Character 'W'` which we have to replace

`RegEx` for `Replacement` of `WNN` will be `""`

- `""` because we just have to `trim` `W` from `Date`

> **NOTE:-** 
>  I have taken `dummy data` for `testing` purposes. 
>  In order to achive desired `Output`, it is compulsory to run both scenario in proper `order`

`Code` for the Same scenario was stated below:-

```
# Import all-important Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Initialization of 'Data'
data = {
    'ID': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
    'Date': ['2019W1', '2020W2', '2019W1', '2020W2', '2020W11', '2020W52'],
    'Volume': ['9', '11', '39', '23', '34', '53']
}

# Conversion of 'Data' to 'DataFrame'
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Conversion of 'YYYYWN' to 'YYYYWW' Using 'Regex'

# Replacement Logic if your 'week No.' is of Single Digit. i.e.:- 'WN'
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"W(\d)$", "-" + r"0\1", regex = True)

# Replacement Logic if your 'week No.' is of Multiple Digit. i.e.:- 'WNN'
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"W", "-" + r"", regex = True)

# Print Records
df
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    ID  Date     Volume
0   1   2019-01  9
1   1   2020-02  11
2   2   2019-01  39
3   2   2020-02  23
4   3   2020-11  34
5   3   2020-52  53
```

Comment: Can you put an explanation for the regex? And also the replacing value `r"0\1"`?

Comment: I have a feeling this is not going to work when you have a week number greater than 9.

Comment: @MarkRansom , was just about to make this comment.. once week is 2020W11 .. output is 2020-011

Comment: @tjjudge Sorry, I don't know about that scenario. I have updated `Code` with proper explanation. If it still throws some wrong result then please tell me.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I have updated `Code` with proper explanation.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for spotting light on this scenario. I have updated my `code`. Does there is any other `test-cases` that may `fail` in our updated `code`?

Comment: `$` does not do what you described.

Comment: @JayPatel How do we implement both into a dataframe with both Wn and Wnn. See question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67201667/15492238

Answer (score 0):

Let us just do

```
df.Date.str.replace('W','-')
0    2019-1
1    2020-2
2    2019-1
3    2020-2
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this custom code

```
def custom_date(x):
    year = str(x)[:4]
    dict_month = {"W1":"01","W2":'02',"W3":'03',"W4":'04'}
    return year+"-"+dict_month.get(f"{str(x)[4:]}","NA")

df['Date']=df.Date.apply(lambda x:custom_date(x))
```